# How to download password protected video from dailymotion

Tags: cookies, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

I have the password to access the video on dailymotion but I cannot download it using `yt-dlp`. I get the error `ERROR: [dailymotion] x7yqr1a: This user does not have access to the video. A password must be provided.`  but I am already providing the password.

I've tried using `--video-password "password" "url"` (both with and without quotes) and I've tried entering the password into the video and then grabbing the cookies and putting it into cookies.txt file: `--cookies "path/to/cookies.txt"`

Both method returns ERROR: [dailymotion] x7yqr1a: This user does not have access to the video. A password must be provided.

Here's what I treid (I removed URL for privacy reasons and the "password" is just arbitrary)

`yt-dlp -c -P "/Users/Macbook/" -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -f "bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best"  --video-password "password" "URL"`

and

`yt-dlp -c -P "/Users/Macbook/" -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -f "bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best" "URL" --cookies "path/to/cookies.txt"`